# No se han especificado valores para algunos parametros (EXCEL/VB.NET/OLEDB)

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

Muy buenas comunidad! El siguiente problema ya lo habia experimentado antes cuando hacia modificaciones (UPDATES) a la hoja de excel, pero siempre le encontraba alguna solucion... pero... ahora no... y lo mas gracioso que estoy siguiendo al pie de la letra los pasos que menciona microsoft en su pagina oficial (esta en ingles): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316934

> With ADO.NET, you can insert and update records in a workbook in one of three ways:
> Directly run a command to insert or update records one at a time. To do this, you can create an **OLEDbCommand** object on your connection and set its **CommandText** property to a valid command to insert records
>
> INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (F1, F2) values ('111', 'ABC')
>
> or a command to update records
>
> **UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET F2 = 'XYZ' WHERE F1 = '111'**
>
> and then call the ExecuteNonQuery method.

En mi programa tengo funciones y metodos que colectan la hoja dependiendo de la columna que se le pasa como parametro, y funciones que devuelven la posicion exacta de una celda vacia o con errores (A1,B2,C15...) he comparado cientos de veces si las funciones estan devolviendo bien lo que se desea, y pues si... todos  estan trabajando bien... entonces el problema seria la misma funcion de sustitucion...

```
Protected Friend Sub reemplazarDato(ByVal DColumn As String, ByVal headerCell As String, ByVal cell As String, ByVal dato As String)
    Dim hoja As String = obtenerHojaActual(DColumn)
    Dim comando As New OleDbCommand
    comando.Connection = conexion
    comando.CommandText = "UPDATE [" & hoja & "$] SET [" & cell & "]=@dato WHERE [" & headerCell & "]=@DColumn"
    comando.Parameters.Add("@dato", OleDbType.Date).Value = dato
    comando.Parameters.Add("@DColumn", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DColumn
    MsgBox(comando.CommandText)
    MsgBox("Dato nuevo: " + comando.Parameters(0).Value + " en la columna: " + comando.Parameters(1).Value)
    conexion.Open()
    Try
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        cajaMensaje("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
    End Try
    conexion.Close()
    comando.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Esos message box se los inserte para comprobar que los datos se estan insertando bien y la consulta esta siendo bien escrita. Voy a citar un ejemplo que estoy intentando ahora... estoy intentando cambiar el valor de la celda C2 de esta hoja de excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El commandText que imprime el mssgbox del programa...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Notese la similitud al de microsoft: **UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET F2 = 'XYZ' WHERE F1 = '111'**

¿Sera que los parametros no estan almacenando los valores?, pues si lo hacen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y antes que me respondan "es que tienes que removerle los corchetes a los valores que representen columnas", pues no, ya se los he removido y no funciona igual (ademas, la misma pagina sugiere que se utilizen a la hora de marcar columnas), tambien intente haciendo una consulta regular con concatenaciones e igual, nada (tambien la misma pagina sugiere que se utilizen consultas con parametros a la hora de escribirlos)...

Que podria ser este extraño problema?

**ACTUALIZACION**

Leyendo por la web acerca del problema, encontre algo mas; Necesitas desactivar la propiedad HDR para poder modificar una celda especifica. Inserte un parametro en la propiedad de la coneccion String para señalar si se activara o desactivara en determinada operacion.

```
Protected Friend Property setConnection(ByVal hdr As String) As String
    Set(value As String)
        Try
            conexion.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & value & ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=" & hdr & ";IMEX=0;TypeGuessRows=0;'"
        Catch ex As Exception
            cajaMensaje("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
        End Try
    End Set
    Get
        Return conexion.ConnectionString
    End Get
End Property
```

Tambien encontre que se debia señalar un rango para modificar dicha celda. Hice lo siguiente pero no me funciono (Me arroja el mismo error...) y sinceramente no llegue a comprender eso del rango. El metodo entonces quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
   Protected Friend Sub reemplazarDato(ByVal DColumn As String, ByVal cell As String, ByVal dato As String)
    Dim hoja As String = obtenerHojaActual(DColumn)
    Dim comando As New OleDbCommand
    setConnection("NO") = setRuta
    MsgBox(conexion.ConnectionString)
    comando.Connection = conexion
    comando.CommandText = "UPDATE [" & hoja & "$" & cell & ":" & cell & "] SET [" & cell & "]=@dato"
    MsgBox(comando.CommandText)
    comando.Parameters.Add("@dato", OleDbType.VarChar, dato.Length).Value = dato
    conexion.Open()
    Try
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        cajaMensaje("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
    End Try
    conexion.Close()
    comando.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la `ConnectionString`? ¿Probaste poniendo `?` en lugar de los nombres de los parámetros `@dato` y `@DColumn`?

Comment: Hablas de colocarlo asi? "UPDATE [" & hoja & "$] SET [" & cell & "]=@? WHERE [" & headerCell & "]=@?" @Aprendiendo.NET

Comment: Dejame actualizar la pregunta para añadir informacion que descubri por la web @Aprendiendo.NET

Comment: `UPDATE [" & hoja & "$] SET [" & cell & "]=? WHERE [" & headerCell & "]=?` Así tal vez funcione.

Comment: Estoy mirando la conexión y me parece que hay un error en `Excel 8.0`, debería decir `Excel 12.0 xml`, para mayor seguridad fijate en [Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/). Aparte de eso parece que en 64 bits no funciona, para más detalle, fijate en [Jet for Access, Excel and Txt on 64 bit systems](https://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estuve depurando el código sobre **32 bits**, y encontré la causa del problema.

Son muy útiles los enlaces de la pregunta, especialmente [How To Use ADO.NET to Retrieve and Modify Records in an Excel Workbook With Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316934)

---

Para hacer `UPDATE` en un hoja **Excel**, tenemos dos opciones: con o sin encabezado.

### 1. Con encabezado o también llamada actualización de registros

El encabezado es el nombre de las columnas, y cuando se halla presente se debe indicar en la cadena de conexión, mediante la propiedad `HDR=YES`:

```vb
conexion.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                            "Data Source=" & value & ";" &
                            "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;TypeGuessRows=0;'"
'-----------------------------------------------------------^
```

De esta forma podemos hacer la sentencia `UPDATE` como la hacemos para cualquier consulta hacia una base de datos:

`UPDATE Tabla SET campo1 = valor1, campo2 = valor2, ...`

Para el código de la pregunta:

```vb
comando.CommandText =
    "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Date] = DateSerial(2016, 9, 19) WHERE Name = 'Daniel'"

' Con parámetros:
comando.CommandText = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Date] = ? WHERE Name = ?"
```

La columna `C` tiene el nombre `Date`, que es una palabra reservada, y por lo tanto se hace imprescindible el uso de los corchetes, `[` y `]` en cambio `Name` vemos que no los necesita.

Curiosamente funciona `Excel 8.0` para el motor `ACE 12.0`

---

### 2. Sin encabezado o también llamada actualización de celdas individuales

Esta vez, en la cadena de conexión debemos establecer la propiedad `HDR=NO`:

```vb
conexion.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                            "Data Source=" & value & ";" &
                            "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;'"
' ---------------------------------------------------------------^
```

`IMEX` y `TypeGuessRows` no se pueden usar aquí porque dependen de que las filas tengan encabezado de columnas, es decir que sólo se usan cuando `HDR=YES`

Aquí la sentencia `UPDATE`, exige unas normas a seguir:

- Especificar el rango de celdas que serán actualizadas.
- En lugar de los nombres de columnas, se usa la letra **F** seguida de un ordinal, que indica la columna.

Por ejemplo, para cambiar el encabezado:

```
     A         B        C      D    ...
  +------+-----------+------+-----+---
1 | Name | Last_name | Date | Age |     <=== Encabezado
  +------+-----------+------+-----+---
2 |      |           |      |     |
...
```

por el nombre de las celdas:

```
     A         B        C      D    ...
  +------+-----------+------+-----+---
1 |  A1  |     B1    |  C1  |  D1 |     <=== Encabezado
  +------+-----------+------+-----+---
2 |      |           |      |     |
...
```

Se debe hacer:

```vb
comando.CommandText = "UPDATE [Sheet1$A1:D1] SET F1 = 'A1', F2 = 'B1', F3 = 'C1', F4 = 'D1'"

' Con parámetros:
comando.CommandText = "UPDATE [Sheet1$A1:D1] SET F1 = ?, F2 = ?, F3 = ?, F4 = ?"
```

Para el código de la pregunta:

```vb
comando.CommandText = "UPDATE [Sheet1$C2:C2] SET [F1] = DateSerial(2016, 9, 19)"

' Con parámetros:
comando.CommandText = "UPDATE [Sheet1$C2:C2] SET [F1] = ?"
```

Usé `DateSerial`, para evitar problemas con el formato de fechas.

Siempre se debe indicar el rango de celdas, aunque una sola se actualice.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda de nuevo! ya puedo entender mejor como trabajar con excel por medio de consultas.... esta pregunta sera valiosa para la comunidad :)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, y debo resaltar que, en este caso, la pregunta estuvo muy bien elaborada, y eso ayudó muchísimo a dar con la solución.