# ¿Como grabar un valor como número en una hoja de excel? (EXCEL/VB.NET/OLE.DB)

Tags: vb.net, excel

Resulta que al insertar un número en una columna en excel (con formato numerico establecido anteriormente), al abrir la hoja de excel en la casilla se marca el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que el dato se esta grabando como un numero gracias a la siguiente linea:

```
comando.Parameters.Add("@dato", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Val(dato)
```

¿Sera que es normal que aparesca tal cosa o estoy escribiendo algo incorrecto?

Comment: Estuve probando `Excel 12.0 Xml` con `UPDATE` de celdas individuales, y funciona bien. Pero en lugar de `comando.Parameters.Add("@dato", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Val(dato)` puse `comando.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Val(dato)` y en la consulta puse `UPDATE [Hoja1$D7:D7] SET F1 = ?`. dato es de tipo `string` y el archivo es `xlsx`

Comment: Hola! mira con grabar datos de tipo texto no tengo problemas... el problema es al grabar datos numericos en una columna ya definida como numerica (en la hoja de excel), es como si vb.net los metiera como texto siempre aunque señale que el valor es un integer... (Por eso señala tal error de la imagen) @Aprendiendo.NET

Comment: Sí, pero según las nuevas pruebas que hice, si las celdas están definidas como numéricas, debería funcionar. Recién publiqué una respuesta, fijate si te ayuda a solucionar el problema.

Comment: @TwoDent yo también sufrí por este problema en C#, no encuentro la referencia, pero lo que tuve que hacer es formatear primero el valor numérico "en tu caso, usando VB.NET" y luego enviarlo como texto; según la fuente, menciona que Excel _maneja_ estos valores según lo que detecte, así que, si conviertes el valor numérico "digamos, Double" con formato "N2", y lo envías como texto, el archivo Excel reonocerá este valor como numérico, inténtalo y nos comentas.

Comment: @Mauricio gracias por tus comentarios! intente lo que me dices, pero aun sigue marcando el dichoso cuadro verde... Intentare algo que se me ocurrio usando la respuesta de abajo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las primeras pruebas las hice sobre la columna `D` que tenía sólo números, pero definida de tipo `General`. Todo funcionó correctamente.

Ahora hice otras pruebas, y en este caso, puse en la celda `D7` el texto `a` en lugar del número que tenía, que era `6`. Luego de guardar el archivo `xlsx` fui a **VB.NET** y realicé el `UPDATE`, y en **Excel** apareció el problema que comentas: en lugar del número `6` se guardó el texto `6`.

Intenté borrar la celda, guardar un `NULL` en ella, un `0`; pero nada funcionó. **Excel** sabe que la celda es de tipo `General`, entonces mira el dato que ésta tiene guardado y actúa en consecuencia: si tiene un texto, aunque **VB.NET** envíe un número, lo guardará como texto.

Este error sólo apareció en la modalidad de *actualización por celdas individuales*, y sólo cuando la celda que se intenta actualizar está definida como `General`.

Cuando se actualiza un rango de celdas con números, y en una de ellas un texto, igualmente sigue funcionando.

También funciona cuando la celda está definida como numérica, aunque tenga un texto. (**EDICIÓN:** Esto es **incorrecto**, cuando la celda tiene un texto, aunque esté definida como numérica, y aunque se le envíe un número, almacenará un texto. Sí funcionará si está vacía y se le envía un número, siendo numérica; pero no si está definida como `General`)

Cuando utilicé la modalidad de *actualización por registros* (`HDR=YES`) [►](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24286/10998), todo funcionó correctamente, sin importar cómo están definidas las celdas.

Conclusión para solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, se puede optar por alguna de las siguientes alternativas:

- En **Excel** definir las celdas usando el formato numérico. (`Excel > Inicio > Celdas > Formato > Formato de celdas > Número`). **Cuidando que ninguna tenga texto.**
- En lugar de actualizar por *celdas individuales* (`HDR=NO`), optar por la [*actualización por registros*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24286/10998).
- Actualizar un rango que tenga números.
- Si se quiere mantener las celdas definidas como `General`, entonces se debería cuidar que todas las celdas que se actualizarán con números, tengan un `0` numérico en lugar de estar vacías; y ninguna debería tener texto.

Me parece que la más adecuada es la opción primera, porque permite usar ambos tipos de acutalización [►](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24286/10998), y no requiere de un rango para que funcione, y además las celdas pueden estar vacías.

Otra alternativa sería optar por **Automatización OLE** en lugar de **ADO.NET**, para tener acceso a las librerías de **Excel**, pero esto se desvía de la pregunta que requiere `OLE DB`

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder! como veras, estoy evitando en lo posible utilizar COM....  Intento hacer todo full OleDb. Ya se me ocurrio una forma, te agradesco mucho la respuesta.

Comment: De nada, espero haber contribuido con la solución, pero si encuentras otra forma para que la celda que tiene texto pase a tener número, usando el `UPDATE ... SET F1 = ?`, entonces compártela, te agradeceríamos mucho.

Comment: Me re sirvio la solución planteada!